# Yaakov in Sukkot and in Egypt

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

We are told that Yaakov went to a place named Sukkot after meeting Eisav (Bereshit 33:17). 
The Torah mentions another time Sukkot as a place in Egypt as the Bnei Israel's first stop once they left Raamsess (Shemot 12:37 and Bamidbar 33:5).

Are these two places named Sukkot in the Torah the same?

Comment: Judging that the Succoth Jacob sojourns at is east of the Jordan River, I would assume that the two cities are not the same.

Comment: I like it, would you have a source please?

Comment: Yehoshua 13:27 and Melachim I 7:46.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And what do you think about the Baal Haturim comment on this matter Shemot 12:37 : פרק יב, לז 
סכתה. ב' חסרים. מרעמסס סכתה. ויעקב נסע סכתה (בראשית לג, יז). לומר שבזכות יעקב יצאו ממצרים.

Answer (score 3):

They cannot be the same city. The Sukkot where Bnei Yisrael camps on their way out of Egypt is described as being "at the edge of the desert" ([Shemot 13:20](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0213.htm)). And we know that this Sukkot was west of the Yam Suf, because in [the very next chapter](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0214.htm) they continue their exodus and cross the sea.

The Sukkot where Yaakov sojourned ([Bereishit 33:17](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0133.htm)) is east of the Yarden ([Yehoshua 13:27](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0613.htm) and [Melachim I 7:46](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a07.htm)). Therefore they cannot be the same city.